# Progress bar with redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a background upload process in my react/redux application that updates very frequently.  My reducer looks something like this:

```
export default function progressReducer(state = initialState, action = {}) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case PROGRESS_TOTAL_INCREASE:
      return Object.assign({}, state, {total: state.total + action.amount});
    case PROGRESS_CURRENT_INCREASE:
      let current = state.current + action.amount, total = state.total;
      if (current >= state.total && false) {
        state.total = 0;
        current = 0;
      }
      return {total, current};
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

It works.  Great.  But the redux devtool log fills up *very* quickly with progress actions, drowning out any other actions.  Is this the right approach, or should I be looking at a different way of creating these notifications?

Thanks!

Comment: are you using redux-logger middleware for action logging?

Comment: No, when I refer to the log, I'm just talking about the redux devtools panel

Comment: Is there a good reason for putting this state into the shared app-state (in your case Redux)? Like @random pointed out in his answer, it usually makes thing unnecesarily complicated if you put stuff in app-state that is only used by one component.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are using redux devtools chrome extension, you can just list action that should be hidden in extensions settings.

[image: redux devtools extension settings]

Otherwise, if you have integrated it in your project, checkout [redux-devtools-filter-actions](https://github.com/zalmoxisus/redux-devtools-filter-actions) monitor.

Comment: So then would you say it's OK to use redux like this?  I just wondered if it was somehow a bad practice to emit so many events like that.

Comment: Does it cause performance issues? I did a progress bar in a similar fashion and what happened is that i was getting a lot of react re-renders - but I think this is normal.

Comment: @user37078 I think it's fine to use redux this way.  You do indeed get many renders, but that's what's great about react because it only actually updates the DOM where needed, so this happens mostly in memory not DOM, mitigating many of the issues of rendering often.  Plus to create the UI effect you want, you'll need to keep rendering, there's no way around that.  That said, sometimes I use component state for things like this because the rest of my redux app doesn't really care about these events.  That's a stylistic/implementation thing that really depends on your app and it's use cases.

Answer (score 6):

I will start by saying use your common sense, Most of the time it will make the right decision.

Here's what i suggest

- If **multiple components** need to keep track of the upload progress, Its best to **use redux**.
- If only a **specific component** needs to keep track of upload progress, You can just update that **components state**.

  Do remember if you're using components state, you can no longer make use of Pure functional components... as they don't have state
- If you want to use redux but want to keep the store updates minimum, you can just dispatch action when the upload starts and when its completed, and based on this you can render a loading bar.. so visually user will know upload is in progress.